# Colon or comma for direct quotations?

Tags: commas, quotations, colons

I've seen two ways to introduce direction quotations:

1) The host made an announcement, "You are all staying for dinner."

2) The host made an announcement: "You are all staying for dinner."

Is one more correct than the other? Is it a matter of style? The only thing I can find on it is that if the quotation contains two or more sentences, most writers introduce it with a colon.

Comment: It's stylistic. Typically, however, commas are used with dialogue exchanges. (And the number of sentences quoted makes no difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Commas** are typically used in general writing.
**Colons** are mostly used in script writing.

It is just styles that are associated with different kinds of writing. There is no real rule about using colon with multi sentence quote, either.

Comment: Thanks. I got that rule from the Grammar Book colon section: Rule 7. If a quotation contains two or more sentences, many writers and editors introduce it with a colon rather than a comma.